# Google Earth plugin in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, google-earth-plugin

In this the tutorial says you can customize the LINESTRING https://developers.google.com/earth/documentation/geometries?hl=en

but when i try to C# VS2012 the line of code

```
var lineStyle = lineStringPlacemark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
```

i cant find the method getLineStyle()  so i get the error;

error:
Error1 GEPlugin.IKmlStyleSelector' does not contain a definition for 'getLineStyle' and no extension method 'getLineStyle' accepting a first argument of type 'GEPlugin.IKmlStyleSelector' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Here is my full code:

```
    var lineStringPlaceMark = m_ge.createPlacemark("");
    var lineString = m_ge.createLineString("");
    lineStringPlaceMark.setGeometry(lineString);
    lineString.setExtrude(5);
    lineString.setTessellate(500);
    lineString.setAltitudeOffset(5);
    lineString.setAltitudeMode(m_ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

    for (int x = 0; x < arraylat.Length; x++)
    {
        lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(Convert.ToDouble(arraylat[x]), Convert.ToDouble(arraylong[x]), 0);
    }
    //lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(Convert.ToDouble(arraylat[counter]), Convert.ToDouble(arraylong[counter]), 0);



     lineStringPlaceMark.setStyleSelector(m_ge.createStyle("").getLineStyle());

    if (null == lineStringPlaceMark.getStyleSelector())
    {
        lineStringPlaceMark.setStyleSelector(m_ge.createStyle("").getLineStyle());
    }
    var lineStyle =  m_ge.createStyle("").getLineStyle();
    lineStyle.setWidth(100);
    lineStyle.getColor().set("9900ffff");

   /* var lineStyle = lineStringPlaceMark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
     lineStyle.setWidth(lineStyle.getWidth() + 2);
         lineStyle.getColor().set("6600ffff");
    // The Style of a Feature is retrieved as feature.getStyleSelector().
    // The Style itself contains a LineStyle, which is what we manipulate
    // to change the color and width of the line.

    */
    m_ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlaceMark);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would first need to create the actual style object via `GEPlugin.createStyle()`  before you can use it.

There are a few errors in your code. The lines

`lineStringPlaceMark.setStyleSelector(m_ge.createStyle("").getLineStyle());`

and

`var lineStyle =  m_ge.createStyle("").getLineStyle();`

looking at it you would need to do something like.

```
var lineStringPlaceMark = m_ge.createPlacemark(string.Empty);
var lineString = m_ge.createLineString(string.Empty);
lineStringPlaceMark.setGeometry(lineString);
lineString.setExtrude(5);
lineString.setTessellate(500);
lineString.setAltitudeOffset(5);
lineString.setAltitudeMode(m_ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);

for (int x = 0; x < arraylat.Length; x++)
{
    lineString.getCoordinates().pushLatLngAlt(
      Convert.ToDouble(arraylat[x]),
      Convert.ToDouble(arraylong[x]), 0);
}

// we know the placemark has no style, so create one for it
lineStringPlaceMark.setStyleSelector(m_ge.createStyle(string.Empty));

// now you can access the style object 
var lineStyle = lineStringPlaceMark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
lineStyle.setWidth(100);
lineStyle.getColor().set("9900ffff");

m_ge.getFeatures().appendChild(lineStringPlaceMark);
```

You could also make a simple static method that returns the style selector for any feature, creating it if it doesn't exist.

```
// getStyleSelector wrapper, creates a style object if non is present
static dynamic GetStyleSelector(dynamic ge, dynamic feature) {
  if(null == feature.getStyleSelector()) {
      feature.setStyleSelector(ge.createStyle(string.Empty));
  }

  return feature.getStyleSelector();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply but still i cant use the getLinestyle method. i added the code above but i have an error again, here is my code          if (!lineStringPlaceMark.getStyleSelector())  <--here the error 
            {
                lineStringPlaceMark.setStyleSelector(m_ge.createStyle(""));
            }

            var lineStyle = lineStringPlaceMark.getStyleSelector().getLineStyle();
               linestyle.setWidth(5);
            linestyle.getColor().set("9900ffff");

Comment: Here is the error: Error 1 Operator '!' cannot be applied to operand of type 'GEPlugin.IKmlStyleSelector. and the same error i get in the question above

Comment: Ah sorry, missed the C# part - simply convert to a boolean or test for `null` then, or just create the style without testing first. Please see my edit.

Comment: thanks sir for the faster response i appreciated it so much But sir still the error is the same in the LineStlye

Comment: You need to post your full code or an example then, show how you are creating the placemark, etc.

Comment: sir I edited  my question sir may you look at it please.

Comment: ok, I see the error -      `lineStringPlaceMark.setStyleSelector(m_ge.createStyle("").getLineStyle());` should be `lineStringPlaceMark.setStyleSelector(m_ge.createStyle(""));`

Comment: still no luck sir, did you have Teamviewer installed in your pc? if you have time to remote and see my code ;). I badly need this to fix

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46129/discussion-between-user2597863-and-fraser)